# StrongNameSignatureVerification access violation

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, access-violation, strongname

I have an .NET executable assembly which references an unmanaged C++ dll through P/invoke.
After strong name signing the .net asembly I am getting Access violations at some random points when accessing the unmanaged dll. Then I recompilled the assembly without signing it and still getting the same errors. Running it through DebugDiag I get the follwing from the crash report

```
second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at 0x00963c37 which does not correspond to any known native module in the process has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x0000000c on thread 10

Thread 10 - Entry point   clr!StrongNameSignatureVerification+16491
Create time   4/1/2013 12:10:32 ìì
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:2.515
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 0:0:0.125

73  0x79206dc9  0x00000000  clr!StrongNameErrorInfo+966b    0x00000000
74  0x792084c5  0x0477ffb4  clr!StrongNameErrorInfo+ad67    clr!StrongNameErrorInfo+941c
75  0x792f76e0  0x0477ffec  clr!StrongNameSignatureVerification+164d9   0x00000000
```

Which makes me think that it still looks up the verification. I don't get how this happens

On another note,can strong named assemblies refence unamanged dlls?

Comment: Your symbols are probably not correct, it is unlikely that the `StrongNameSignatureVerification` function is over 89kB in size, which it would have to for that offset to be valid. It, and the `StrongNameErrorInfo` are showing up because they're the closest symbols the debugger knows about. It's much more likely you made an error with the P/Invoke signature and/or are passing `null` to it (given the "small" address in the exception information).

Comment: Use the debugger to work out what's going wrong. Find out which calls to the native DLL are failing.